# How to pass Boost UUID random generator output to main

Tags: c++, boost

I am trying to learn how Boost UUID works. I have made the following code

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>            
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp> 
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace uuids;

int main() {

    for (int i = 0; i < 40; ++i){
        uuid uuid = random_generator()();
        cout <<i+1<<"     "<<"\t"<<uuid << endl;
    }
    system("pause");

    return 0;
}
```

In this code i generate 40 lines with UUID codes. I want to place these lines in a function and call them by my main class `int main()`

Any ideas how to do this?

Comment: Not sure what you are asking? Are you just trying to move this very same loop into a function? Or should the function return the uuids to `main`? Either way, that's pretty basic so you should try your code first and post what is not working.

Comment: the function should return uuids to main :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generate them into a standard library container, such as e.g. `std::vector<uuid>`:

```
std::vector<uuid> foo() {
    std::vector<uuid> r;
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(r), 40, random_generator());
    return r;
}
```

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43d6dc1201e5b293)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/uuid/uuid.hpp>            
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_generators.hpp> 
#include <boost/uuid/uuid_io.hpp> 
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
using namespace boost;
using namespace uuids;

std::vector<uuid> foo() {
    std::vector<uuid> r;
    std::generate_n(back_inserter(r), 40, random_generator());
    return r;
}


int main() {
    for(auto& uuid : foo())
        cout << uuid << endl;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That helped alot. Forgot that i could use the vector class :-)

Comment: They're different each time (as they are random): [first run](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/43d6dc1201e5b293), and [another run](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dbe16454e74c066b)